# Differences in Sharepoint Syntax and structure

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

As a full-stack developer developing towards SharePoint-based, Customized projects, I have for a while pondered around the necessity of having diffferent syntax-flavours for Powershell-Module that targets the different versions of SharePoint.
I'm not a heavy SharePoint-Powershell user in my daily work.

My question is simply: why do SharePoint Server commands, PnP PowerShell and SharePointOnlinePowerShell exist separately with different syntax.

Example:
'Get-SpUser'
'Get-PnPUser'
'Get-SPOUser'

Why isn't there a unified SharePoint Powershell Syntax?